# Append Url value to select dropdown menu using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using textbox with attached dropdown menu. Textbox is searching for the person name and dropdown list comes different categories.

I used to send the search value and dropdown list selected value to the url and getting the results, but after displaying the results the dropdown menu value is changing. I am getting the url, but cannot append to the select dropdown menu.

Here in the url I am getting the value of the dropdown need to append to dropdown list as a text.

```
<select id="menu">  
     <option value = "all"> All </option>
     <option value = "people"> People </option>
     <option value = "conversations"> Conversations </option>
     <option value = "products"> Products </option>
     <option value = "circles"> Circles </option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.href;
    var urlVal = pathname.substr(pathname.indexOf('='));
    var url = urlVal.split('=');
    var url2 = url[1].split('&');
});
```

Comment: please include js. and specify where to append the url. append as text or attr value?

Comment: I have included the js file how can I append the text to the select dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

when result comes depend on that you have to select option forcefully
like

```
$('#menu option:contains(' + resultOption + ')"').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: I have selected the people from the dropdown menu and included some text in the textbox and searched. After getting the result the dropdown value changed to default all

Comment: ie. page refreshed so you have to code for add that selected option